# Modal is still on screen even though visible={this.props.bool} and this.props.bool is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Basically, I console.log a value in render, and in a Modal pass visible={the_value}. The Chrome debugger states the value is false, but the modal is still there... Even react-devtools says its false. Could it be an emulator issue?

Another concern is: with this code I'm uploading an "announcement" to a Firebase Realtime DB. When I upload just text (a quick async event), the issue of the modal not going away occurs. When I upload a large image (a longer async event) the modal goes away. Is this a helpful clue? Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

I've tried setting a value in state as the the_value in the constructor, but it never becomes true. I've also tried visible={this.props.isPushingA}

```js
constructor(props) {
//...
 this.state = { //...
   waitModalVisible: this.props.isPushingA 
 };
}
//...
render() {
 console.log(this.state.waitModalVisible);
 const { failMsgHeight, successMsgHeight } = this.state;
 if (this.props.isSuccess) {
   // animate the showing of the failMSG
   failMsgHeight.setValue(0); // reset the animated value
   Animated.timing(successMsgHeight, {
     toValue: (height / 20), // proportional error msg
     duration: 1000,
     easing: Easing.cubic,
   }).start();
 } else {
   // animate the hiding of the failMSG
   Animated.timing(successMsgHeight, {
     toValue: 0,
     duration: 1000,
     easing: Easing.linear
  }).start();
 } //...
 return (
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
<Animated.View style={{ backgroundColor: '#228B22', height: successMsgHeight }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, margin: 5, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
          Success!
        </Text>
</Animated.View
  //...
  <Modal
        visible={this.state.waitModalVisible} 
       // also have tried visible={this.props.isPushingA}
       // this.props.isPushingA is in mapStateToProps
        transparent
        onRequestClose={() => this.props.isAnnouncePushing(false)}
      >
 //...
 );
 //...
}
```

I would expect the modal to go away after my action (redux-thunk) does its thing, but it never does. I even see the Animated.View pop up in the background, further proof that the correct/current props have been passed to the component, and render is happening.

EDIT: console.log waitModalVisible in render shows that its always false, while console.log isPushingA shows its true then false

Comment: I have the same problem with android emulator. but it's ok in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

As i see that even after the state is updated, The Modal stays back. You can try the below approach.

```
  {this.state.waitModalVisible && (<Modal
       visible={this.state.waitModalVisible} 
       // also have tried visible={this.props.isPushingA}
       // this.props.isPushingA is in mapStateToProps
        transparent
        onRequestClose={() => this.props.isAnnouncePushing(false)}
  />)}
```

This would just be a work around.

Actual issue would be in your Modal. Check if the property `visible` is received by Modal once `waitModalVisible` is false. If it is not receiving, then you may need to use lifecycle method `getDerivedStateFromProps` and update your Modal state.